# Remove part of searchwords in searchfield with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a searchfunction where people search after partnumbers ending with a hashtag and numbe, eg #000. When doing this, it cant find the matching partnumber (we have it without the hashtag part). The system Im on doesn't let me acces the html directly or the Javascript already on the site, but I have a paste window where I can add html and Javascript.

Is it possible to target my searchfunction with Vanilla Javascript to ignore the hashtag and following strings?

The html for the search:

```
<div class="searching myClass yourClass">

<input type="text" name="_s0_19030953_19030952_sch1" size="17" maxlength="40" id="searchfield" class="searchfield" value="Sök" onfocus="if (value=='Sök'){value=''}else{partHighlight(this.id,0,this.value.length)}" onblur="if (value==''){value='Sök'};lostFocus()" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autoComplete(event);" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 27) {onEscape();return false;} if(UI.getKeyFrom(event)==13) {UI.elem('_s0_19030953_19030952_sch0').onclick(); return false;} removeNewLines(this)"><input type="button" value="" id="_s0_19030953_19030952_sch0" name="_s0_19030953_19030952_sch0" class="searchbutton" onclick="UI.pb(this, 'click'); return false;"><div class="autosuggestions invisible" id="autosuggestions"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="text" name="_s0_19030953_19030952_sch1" size="17" maxlength="40" id="searchfield" class="searchfield" placeholder="Sök"  autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autoComplete(event);" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 27) {onEscape();return false;} if(UI.getKeyFrom(event)==13) {UI.elem('_s0_19030953_19030952_sch0').onclick(); return false;} removeNewLines(this)" />
  <input type="button" value="" id="_s0_19030953_19030952_sch0" name="_s0_19030953_19030952_sch0" class="searchbutton" onclick="UI.pb(this, 'click'); return false;" />
  <div class="autosuggestions invisible" id="autosuggestions"></div>
```

If your form uses method GET, then before sending the data to server you should escape hash character to something other - if in the link there is clean `#` character, NOTHING after it is send to the server.

`#` is `&35;`  if you replace it, then search should work for you.
Or you can use method POST and then there wouldnt be any problems with `#` in values.

PS: Please provide some more data.

Comment: The thing is I cant access the div provided to make those changes, I need to sue javascript to inject it in the DOM then. Thus looking for a Javascript way to target my search. Not sure what more data I can provide? Thanks for the answer! @Seti

Comment: Then just replace `#` into its `&35;` code when you send it to the server or, after page load analyze the link on js side and ask server for the part id.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not an option, my options for this is very limited. I need a javascript way to do this, if possible. And the important part is that I need  to remove the # and the following string from the search. And thanks for the input.  @Seti.

Comment: You can attach event to search form submit then, and clean the data before you send them. We see only a little code of yours, therefore we dont even know how you may deal with the problems - i already gave you 3 or 4 possible ways of doing it.

Comment: Yeah as said, I dont have access to Scripts or the html or anything serverwise, so i can just target it with new scripts or html, whihc doesnät give me more code to share. Hence my problem  :p